# How do I create an object array to load dummy data into dynatree?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, dynatree

I am creating a wireframe that will use dynatree to display a tree.  I would like to load some dummy data into the tree using an object array.  I read the documentation and was able to load the parents using:

```
$(function() {
$("#catTree").dynatree({
   children: ["Category 1","Category 2","Category 3","Category 4","Category 5","Category 6","Category 7","Category 8","Category 9"],
...
```

How do I amend this to show children of these categories?  For example:

Category 1
   sub category1
   sub category2

etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
children: [
  {title: "Item 1"},
  {title: "Item 2",
    children: [
      {title: "Sub-item 2.1"},
      {title: "Sub-item 2.2"}
    ]
  },
  {title: "Item 3"}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

above mentioned object is Javascript object or JSON object?